# RewriteRule first rule works, second rule does not redirect to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to force two http pages to https.  When I did the login page, it works perfectly:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^login\.htm$ https://www.sample.com/dev/login.htm [R=301,NC,L]
```

However, when I tried to add the second page, I got server error with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^login\.htm$ https://www.sample.com/dev/login.htm [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^register\.htm$ https://www.sample.com/dev/register.htm [R=301,NC,L]
```

Obviously, something was wrong.  So I changed it to simply **Redirect** on the second page instead of RewriteRule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^login\.htm$ https://www.sample.com/dev/login.htm [R=301,NC,L]
Redirect ^register\.htm$ https://www.sample.com/dev/register.htm [R=301,NC,L]
```

The site came back, but the second page is not forced to https at all. I have checked all over and it supposed to work, but it doesn't.  Your assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite conditions only apply to the rule that immediately follows. So you have two options:

**Option 1:** Repeat the condition for each rule

```bash
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^login.htm$ https://www.sample.com/dev/login.htm [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^register.htm$ https://www.sample.com/dev/register.htm [R=301,NC,L]
```

**Option 2:** Use one rule that matches both URIs

```bash
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(login|register).htm$ https://www.sample.com/dev/$1.htm [R=301,NC,L]
```